# Скоростная верстка

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Вопрос в следующем: хочется научиться верстать быстро. Реально быстро, при этом, не "нарабатывая опыт годами". Что я имею в виду?

Например, есть стандартный шаблон для трехколоночного сайта.

> `ШАПКА
> ЛЕВАЯ_СТОРОНА
> ПРАВАЯ_СТОРОНА
> ЦЕНТР
> ПОДВАЛ`

С этим шаблоном почти никто не спорит, почти все его используют. Вот хотелось бы узнать таких шаблонов побольше. Лучше, в виде онлайн руководства с примерами (ведь большинство дизайнов содержат общие элементы).

Что интересует в первую очередь.

1. Отцентрованное горизонтальное меню в резиновой верстке с переменной шириной кнопок и выпадающими подменюшкми.
   Без подменюшек легко: display: table-cell.
2. Блок, отцентрированный по вертикали относительно пустой страницы. Точнее, почему иногда он может не центроваться.
3. Затемнение от модального диалога.

По отдельности, эти примеры найти несложно. Хотелось бы все вместе (или ответа, что всего вместе нет), притом, чтобы оно было "правильно" сверстано.

Comment: что мешает все это взять и слепить воедино?

Comment: Ничего не мешает. Но на поиск решений по-отдельности тратится энное время. И не всегда найденный результат вполне себе грамотный.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://csstemplater.com/ и, если не подошло, http://www.google.ru/search?q=html+generator. Это первая часть вопроса.

Comment: мммм.... это уже почти что нужно. Но это совсем первая часть. Это генерация глобальных шаблонов. Их я уже знаю. Меня больше интересуют всякие мелкие внутренние фичи. Для этого я и привел примеры=)

Answer (score 11):

[Emmet](http://emmet.io/) значительно [повышает](https://habrahabr.ru/post/175747/) скорость вёрстки.

Comment: Ненене =) Скорость печатания слов у меня нормальная. Ненормальная скорость осознавания как предложенный макет запихать в блоки.

Answer (score 5):

Советую поискать по фразе css framework. Скорее всего то, что нужно.

Answer (score 4):

ну вам значит повезло с одинаковыми по структуре макетами, лично у меня в работе структура постоянно меняется, и стандартных шаблонов я уже почти не вижу, везде куча динамики скриптов, нестандартные расположения, и уже наверно за последний год я не видел ни одного стандартного шаблона, никто не хочет быть как все, всем нужна оригинальность.
Так что отвечая на ваш вопрос могу сказать что быстро научится верстать не получится.

Comment: Что, у вас никто не хочет всплывающей картинки в галерее? Навязчивой формочки регистрации в том же диалоге? Нестандартно плавающего в шапке телефона? Толпы улыбающихся девушек, таскающих разные элементы сайта? Бесконечного списка товаров в каталоге с картинками и кучей описания, которое может разворачиваться, не разламывая весь сайт? Тогда вам, конечно, очень повезло. Но лично мне встречаются именно такие...

Comment: knes, я ж и говорю у меня такие же клиенты как и у вас,клиентов с версткой под стандарт я уже давно не видел.

Answer (score 2):

"Архитектура" сайта, как и паттерны проектирования всегда зависит от потребностей. Например, сайт-визитка или сайт-"ларёк" не нуждаются в шаблонах вообще, так как парочка фоток и несколько абзацев текста не нуждаются в сложной структуре, да и структуре вообще...

Comment: Это все хорошо. Но часто приходится верстать отнюдь не ларьки. А знать шаблоны, которые применимы ко всем видам сайтов всегда полезно.

Comment: сядь за вечер открой пару сайтов\придумай шаблоны сам и сверстай для них хтмл разметку, потом в будущем будешь себе подставлять код и все? или куда быстрее?? возьми какой-то редактор, наприме дримВьювер, там все мишкой накидай - он тебе сам разметку с генерирует и все

Comment: Если уж так, то разрабатывать шаблоны  можно и самому....а что тут сложного? Сел, за пару минут на коленке набросал сколько надо div`ов и все! Делов то =)

Comment: @Asen, 
набросал сколько надо div`ов и все// А сколько надо? ^^ Для тех же скругленных уголков есть минимум три решения для старых браузеров. 
а что тут сложного?// Сложного ничего. Но надо быстро.

Answer (score 1):

1. Использование flexbox вместо хаков float, clear и т.д.
2. Методология BEM сильно повышает создание (за счёт простоты) и дальнейшее сопровождение.

Comment: BEM - это далеко не про "скоростную" верстку.

Answer (score 0):

Единственное, что реально повышает скорость разработки, так это использование продвинутой IDE и препроцессоров. Для `HTML` - это `Pug` (бывший `Jade`), А для `CSS` - `Stylus`.

Препроцессоры мало того, что сокращают написание кода, так еще и улучшают его восприятие. Да и запутаться с написание закрывающих конструкций в `Pug` и `Stylus` тяжело - ведь их там попросту нет. Ну и "прорекламирую" свою [разработку](https://github.com/1000tech/web-starter-kit), в которой настроены по-умолчанию компиляции препроцессоров, генерации шрифтов и оптимизация графики.